# Spring Boot: Why can't I connect to two different databases?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am modeling my code off of this code online:
https://github.com/snicoll-demos/demo-multi-entity-managers

This is my console output:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.6.RELEASE)

2016-08-15 11:30:45.586  INFO 8056 --- [           main] database.Application                     : Starting Application on LR90KLWJY with PID 8056 (C:\Users\vincni\git\consumer_load_method\bin started by vincni in C:\Users\vincni\git\consumer_load_method)
2016-08-15 11:30:45.586  INFO 8056 --- [           main] database.Application                     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-08-15 11:30:45.633  INFO 8056 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@15bfd87: startup date [Mon Aug 15 11:30:45 PDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-15 11:30:46.789  INFO 8056 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'lmPersistenceUnit'
2016-08-15 11:30:46.804  INFO 8056 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: lmPersistenceUnit
    ...]
2016-08-15 11:30:46.867  INFO 8056 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
2016-08-15 11:30:46.867  INFO 8056 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-08-15 11:30:46.867  INFO 8056 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-08-15 11:30:47.023  INFO 8056 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-08-15 11:30:47.647  WARN 8056 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.d.i.StandardDialectResolver      : HHH000385: Unknown Microsoft SQL Server major version [12] using SQL Server 2000 dialect
2016-08-15 11:30:47.662  INFO 8056 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
2016-08-15 11:30:47.693  INFO 8056 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-08-15 11:30:47.771  INFO 8056 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2016-08-15 11:30:47.771  INFO 8056 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
2016-08-15 11:30:47.771  INFO 8056 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000396: Updating schema
2016-08-15 11:30:47.771  INFO 8056 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000232: Schema update complete
2016-08-15 11:30:47.818  INFO 8056 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'mtsPersistentUnit'
2016-08-15 11:30:47.818  INFO 8056 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: mtsPersistentUnit
    ...]
2016-08-15 11:30:48.005  INFO 8056 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
2016-08-15 11:30:48.005  INFO 8056 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-08-15 11:30:48.005  INFO 8056 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2016-08-15 11:30:48.005  INFO 8056 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
2016-08-15 11:30:48.005  INFO 8056 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000396: Updating schema
2016-08-15 11:30:48.005  INFO 8056 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000232: Schema update complete
2016-08-15 11:30:48.068  WARN 8056 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'demo' defined in database.Application: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [database.loadmethod.repositories.LoadMethodRepository]: No qualifying bean of type [database.loadmethod.repositories.LoadMethodRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [database.loadmethod.repositories.LoadMethodRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
2016-08-15 11:30:48.083  INFO 8056 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'mtsPersistentUnit'
2016-08-15 11:30:48.083  INFO 8056 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'lmPersistenceUnit'
2016-08-15 11:30:48.083 ERROR 8056 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'demo' defined in database.Application: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [database.loadmethod.repositories.LoadMethodRepository]: No qualifying bean of type [database.loadmethod.repositories.LoadMethodRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [database.loadmethod.repositories.LoadMethodRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at database.Application.main(Application.java:25) [bin/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [database.loadmethod.repositories.LoadMethodRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted

2016-08-15 11:30:48.083  INFO 8056 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Users/vincni/git/consumer_load_method/bin/, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.camel/camel-ftp/jars/camel-ftp-2.16.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.camel/camel-core/bundles/camel-core-2.16.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core/jars/jaxb-core-2.2.11.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl/jars/jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/com.jcraft/jsch/jars/jsch-0.1.53.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/commons-net/commons-net/jars/commons-net-3.3.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/jars/HikariCP-2.4.7.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/jars/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/jars/spring-boot-starter-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/jars/spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-core/jars/spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-context/jars/spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-aop/jars/spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/aopalliance/aopalliance/jars/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-beans/jars/spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-expression/jars/spring-expression-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/jars/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/jars/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/jars/logback-core-1.1.7.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/jars/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/jars/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/jars/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.yaml/snakeyaml/bundles/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/jars/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/jars/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/jars/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/jars/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.36.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-juli/jars/tomcat-juli-8.0.36.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/jars/spring-jdbc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-tx/jars/spring-tx-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/jars/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/jars/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging-annotations/jars/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/jars/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/dom4j/dom4j/jars/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/xml-apis/xml-apis/jars/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations/jars/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/jars/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.javassist/javassist/bundles/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/antlr/antlr/jars/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.jboss/jandex/jars/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/javax.transaction/javax.transaction-api/jars/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/jars/spring-data-jpa-1.9.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons/jars/spring-data-commons-1.11.4.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-orm/jars/spring-orm-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.springframework/spring-aspects/jars/spring-aspects-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.camel/camel-jpa/jars/camel-jpa-2.10.0.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.camel/camel-spring/bundles/camel-spring-2.10.0.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.poi/poi/jars/poi-3.10.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/commons-codec/commons-codec/jars/commons-codec-1.5.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/jars/poi-ooxml-3.10.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas/jars/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans/jars/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/stax/stax-api/jars/stax-api-1.0.1.jar, file:/C:/apps/Ivy/cache/com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4/jars/sqljdbc4-4.0.jar, file:/C:/ExternalJARS/ojdbc7.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/eclipselink.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/jpa/javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/jpa/org.eclipse.persistence.jpars_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/com.sun.tools.xjc_2.2.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/com.sun.xml.bind_2.2.0.v201004141950.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/javax.activation_1.1.0.v201108011116.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/javax.mail_1.4.0.v201005080615.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/javax.xml.bind_2.2.0.v201105210648.jar, file:/C:/Users/vincni/workspace/workspace_lmt/libraries/EclipseLink%202.5.2/eclipselink/jlib/moxy/javax.xml.stream_1.0.1.v201004272200.jar]
```

This is my application file:

```
@SpringBootApplication//(exclude = HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class)
//@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = {LoadMethodRepository.class /*, TBL_GroupRepository.class*/})
//@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {LoadMethodDO.class /*, TBL_GroupDO.class*/})
//@EnableCaching
public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(LoadMethodRepository lm_repo /*, LMClientRepository lmc_repo */) {
        return (args) -> {

            System.out.println("*********Media ID**************");
            System.out.println(lm_repo.findOne("4948460").getMediaId());
            System.out.println("*********Media ID**************");
        };
    }
```

This is my config file for one of my databases:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "lmEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "lmTransactionManager",
        basePackageClasses = {EventsWithCommentsDO.class, LMClientDO.class, LoadMethodDO.class})
@EnableTransactionManagement
class LM_Config {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource lmDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lmEntityManagerFactory(final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder.dataSource(lmDataSource())
                .packages("lmDataObjects")
                .persistenceUnit("lmPersistenceUnit")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    PlatformTransactionManager lmTransactionManager( @Qualifier("lmEntityManagerFactory") final EntityManagerFactory factory ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }
}
```

This is my config file for the other database:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "mtsEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "mtsTransactionManager",
        basePackages = "database.mts.dataobjects")
public class MTS_Config {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.mtsDatasource")
    public DataSource mtsDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mtsEntityManagerFactory(final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder.dataSource(mtsDataSource())
                .packages("mtsDataObjects")
                .persistenceUnit("mtsPersistentUnit")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager mtsTransactionManager( @Qualifier("mtsEntityManagerFactory") final EntityManagerFactory factory ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }

}
```

This is my properties file:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
spring.datasource.username=xxxxdev
spring.datasource.password=xxxx
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://scherwqvsqlaod:1433;database=dbMOBClientTemp;integratedSecurity=false;
spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
#spring.jpa.database=dbMOBClientTemp
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

spring.mtsDatasource.username=xxxx
spring.mtsDatasource.password=xxxx
spring.mtsDatasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://SCHQVSQERLCON2:1433;database=dbMTS;integratedSecurity=false;
spring.mtsDatasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.mtsDatasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.mtsDatasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.default_schema=dbo
hibernate.packagesToScan=src.repositories.LMClientRepository.java
```

My data object files are just POJO DOs, I have the entity, table, column, and Id annotations.
My load method repository file looks like this

```
public interface LoadMethodRepository extends CrudRepository<LoadMethodDO, String>{

}
```

My project structure is such that I have the application.java file at the topmost level. Every DO, repo, and config file is beneath -- similar to the project linked above.

Comment: I would recommend reviewing the spring-data example for multiple databases: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/multiple-datasources. Once you get that working then check what is different with your application.

Answer (score 0):

The problem as I see is:

> No qualifying bean of type [database.loadmethod.repositories.LoadMethodRepository] found

I think your application have mismatch in configuration. Please, try configure Spring setting where it should search for repositories by adding following annotation to the **Application.class**:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = DataConfig.class)
```

You also need to create corresponding configuration file **DataConfig**:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"database.loadmethod.repositories"})
@Import({LM_Config.class, MTS_Config.class})
public class DataConfig {
}
```

Hope this will help.